# Table view observer error ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, exception

I am not adding any observer but I don't know where I am getting wrong.
While compiling my code I am getting the following error:

> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x18500000 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
>
> Current observation info:  (
>    Context: 0x0, Property: 0x19b5e070>
>    Context: 0x0, Property: 0x19b66520>
>    Context: 0x0, Property: 0x19b669d0>
>   )'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x20921b0b 0x200dedff 0x20921a51 0x210dba91 0x200f93cd 0x22f670e3 0x22f66d55 0x24ef27f5 0x208e32b1 0x208e15a7 0x208e19e5 0x208301c9 0x2082ffbd 0x21e4caf9 0x24f68435 0x1968c4 0x204dc873)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Can you add any of your related code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am using a third party framework which is using my tableview frames and contentOffSet. Now its working fine.